# Compare Round Robin and Multilevel Feedback Queue in terms of waiting time, response time, turnaround time

Tags: optimization, time, jobs, scheduling

I want to make a comparison between RR and MLFQ  in terms of waiting time, response time, turnaround time in 3 cases:

a) More CPU-bounded jobs than I/O
    jobs

b) More I/O-bounded jobs than
    CPU bounded jobs

c) When only a few
    jobs need to schedule.

Could you help me to clarify or give me some sources for reference. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There's some maths for this called "[queueing theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory)", which can give you some equations to use.

Another way is to develop a simulation (software model) of the queue, and measure things (e.g. the distribution of response times) as you change various parameters (e.g. utilization).

The important thing to decide is the distribution of inter-arrival times of the input events (jobs to be processed): if they arrive regularly then there may be typically no queueing delay at all (assuming the system utilization is less than 100%), but if they arrive randomly (e.g. with a Poisson distribution) then there's (on average) a non-zero queue.